# How to update SWT GUI from another thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, swt

I am writing a desktop application using SWT. What is the simplest way to update GUI controls from another thread?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [Display.asyncExec](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html#asyncExec(java.lang.Runnable)) or [Display.syncExec](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html#syncExec(java.lang.Runnable)), depending on your needs.

For example, another thread might call this method to safely update a label:

```
  private static void doUpdate(final Display display, final Label target,
      final String value) {
    display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        if (!target.isDisposed()) {
          target.setText(value);
          target.getParent().layout();
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

- [More here](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/swt_threading.htm?resultof=%22%73%77%74%22%20%22%74%68%72%65%61%64%22%20)

Answer (score 6):

There's a tutorial [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t43753.html).

*"SWT does make a point to fail-fast when it comes to threading problems; so at least the typical problems don't go unnoticed until production. The question is, however, what do you do if you need to update a label/button/super-duper-control in SWT from a background thread? Well, it's surprisingly similar to Swing:"*

```
// Code in background thread.
doSomeExpensiveProcessing();
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
  someSwtLabel.setText("Complete!");
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just sent a message to the GUI thread that some modification has been changed. This is cleaner if you see it from MVC perspective.

Answer (score -1):

When creating the separate thread from the main thread pass the Gui object to the new thread and u can access all the properties of that GUI object.

Comment: Just because the GUI thread has a reference to the GUI object, doesn't mean that it has access to it. You can only update GUI objects from the original thread.