# SWT single threading problem

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

I faced a problem while using threading for the first time, In an SWT program in the main thread I have created the GUI and opened the shell, and then a new thread is started to run some logic in the model, and in the model at a certain state there is a method is called in the GUI class... and here it is the problem
this method is called in the 2nd thread while I want it to be called in the main thread or at least execute it in the main thread

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks,

Comment: Related link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333377/how-to-update-a-gui-from-another-thread-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

External threads can't access GUI. Check `display.asyncExec`.

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/swt_threading.htm

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `asyncExec` or `syncExec` methods in the `Display` class in order to execute a runnable in the main thread:

```
// do stuff in a background thread

// ...then schedule job to run in main thread
display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
   ...
});
```

Both `syncExec` and `asyncExec` will schedule a job in the main (UI) thread as soon as possible. The difference is that `asyncExec` returns immediately, while `syncExec` will not return until the job has completed.