# Class name Cannot be resolved to a type error - Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning Java Programming and I am a beginner. I am in Multithreading Concept now. When I execute the below program, I getting errors like

**Errors**

> X cannot be resolved to a type
>   X cannot be resolved to a type
>
> ThreadX cannot be resolved
>
> at ThreadTest.main(ThreadTest.java:20)

***Code***

```
public Class X implements Runnable
{
        public void run()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("\tValue of ThreaadX : "+i);
            }
            System.out.println("End of ThreadX");
        }
}

public class ThreadTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        X runnable = new X();
        Thread Threadx = new Thread(runnable);
        ThreadX.start();
        System.out.println("END OF THREADX");
    }

}
```

What mistake I did in the Main Method. I getting this error When I tried to create an object 'runnable' of the class X.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `class X` (with a lowercase c). Also you're declaring a variable named `Threadx` and then you're doing `ThreadX.start()`. Java is case-sensitive.

Comment: The program runs perfectly with ZouZou's modifications. Why did you not write that in a comment instead of as an answer ?

Comment: This may be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333377/how-to-update-swt-gui-from-another-thread-in-java

Comment: You might consider using an IDE (e.g. Eclipse, NetBeans). This would highlight this basic syntax errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java syntax is case sensitive

```
Thread Threadx = new Thread(runnable);
ThreadX.start(); //it should be 'x' lowercase at the end of the ThreadX variable
```

You need to change it to

```
  Thread Threadx = new Thread(runnable);
  Threadx.start();
```

Comment: I am getting a new exceptins nw like below

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The public type X must be defined in its own file

 at X.<init>(ThreadTest.java:1)
 at ThreadTest.main(ThreadTest.java:18)**

Comment: That's a different question. but, i will help you. Public Class should have their own file. i.e. you should have X.java for public class X and ThreadTest.java for ThreadTest class

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line `ThreadX.start();` with `Threadx.start();`. Because in java object's name is case sensitive so `ThreadX` is not equivalent to `Threadx`. That's why you were getting error.

Answer (score 0):

use this. Check the name of thread `Threadx`  'x'  small.

```
Thread Threadx = new Thread(runnable);
            Threadx.start();//it is 'X'(capital in your case)
```

[Check out naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)